# WKWebView don't show the website in swift with iOS 9.0

Tags: swift, wkwebview

i try to use WKWebView, but it don' work.

here is my code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebviewVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webview: WKWebView?

// MARK: - ********** Lifecycle **********

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webview = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(webview!)
        webview!.navigationDelegate = self
        loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
        webview!.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

//MARK: - ********** load url ***********

    func loadUrl(urlStr: String) {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr)
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webview!.loadRequest(requestObj)
    }


}
```

i have seted the App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES. but the webView also don't show the website.

pls help!

Comment: nothing is printed in console?

Comment: @Lu_ nothing is printed

Comment: can you print frames of webview or do you see anything?

Comment: @Lu_ i print(webview?.frame), the console show Optional((0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0))

Comment: Debug `url` and `requestObj` objects for be not `nil`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this:

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr)
```

you should use:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)
```